# Can I use this Notepad++ for OS X?

Tags: objective-c, windows, macos, notepad++

I found this notepad++ for mac ,it has a size of 215 megabytes(quite large).
I have downloaded it and started looking at it.

I found this link:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ywh6HlCmtg0

It is actually working pretty good.
I just like to know;
is this OK?,Or Lawful?
if it is not I like to remove this from my computer.
Thanks

Comment: What you're looking at is a terrible, awful, childish WINE port. Using it will be painful.

Comment: @duskwuff ,I got it off my Mac.Thanks

Comment: Something is not right here. The Windows installer for Notepad++ is only 5.56MB, 2.6% of what the 'mac' version is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend you use something like [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) if you want to have a neat text editor. You can use it for free, it just bugs you once in a while, when you save a file. It's full featured either way.

Comment: Thanks,Wow ,This is better than I expected.

Comment: Sure thing! Oh yeah, it's available on all platforms too! :)